# What's the difference between "Free" versus "Free to Play" on Steam?

Tags: steam, terminology

On Steam, there are the labels "Free" and "Free to Play" - what is the difference between the two?

[image: Steam Store showing free and 'free to play' games]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

"Free" means the game is free. 100% free with no charge to play it.

"Free to play" means the base game is free and you can play for free but some content will be available that require micro-transactions or other form of payment to get hold of. [As mentioned on the Steam Support article for "Free to play" games](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8795-TIDH-0077):

> Free to play games are available to download for free and can be played without a subscription or a credit card. Your Steam wallet allows you to purchase items and content in-game to customize your gameplay.

Comment: P2W has a significant overlap with, but is not identical to F2P.  There are plenty of F2P games that only sell cosmetic items.  There are P2W games that also charge for the retail box and/or a periodic subscription.

Comment: * where the interpretation "can play" might heavily depend on how we define "can" and "play".

Comment: Not to forget about the Free to Pay games, where you have all the content from the beginning, but still can buy stuff that does not give you any advantage at all :P

Comment: @Iszi Notice 'Path of Exile' in the list? This is a great example of a F2P game without any P2W content. It does feature microtransactions for item skins and convenience items like bank space, but it's totally optional.

Comment: TF2 would be a good example as well. Whilst yes, you *can* unlock weapons via paying, a) those weapons are not strictly better (or worse) than the stock counterparts, and b) You can unlock the majority of them through random item drops/achivement gets anyway.

Answer (score 9):

It's important to note that in *most* cases, at least on Steam, if a game is listed as "Free to Play" then the additional content which is behind a paywall will be purely cosmetic.

In other words if you want your player character to be wearing a fancy hat or have a weapon which is golden rather than the usual chrome or black finish then you will have to pay for it, but the actual gameplay will usually be unaffected.

Examples of this model are DOTA 2 and Team Fortress 2.

Some other games have items/bonuses etc. which do affect gameplay, which can be unlocked over the course of normal play, but will allow you to unlock these things more quickly by paying some money.

Sometimes you can outright buy these items, or sometimes you will earn free "points" of some type by just playing which can be spent for either cosmetic or gameplay-affecting items, and you can "boost" the rate at which you earn these otherwise free points by paying real money, thus allowing you to unlock the items more quickly (but still requiring you to "earn" the points through some gameplay actions or just time spent playing).

Examples of this model are League of Legends and Marvel Heroes.

Comment: League of Legends has nothing that affects gameplay. If you don't count faster leveling that is, but that does not give you an advantage over other players. Pay for convience != pay to win.

Comment: @Gnarly404 When I used to play you could buy player runes which affected things like attack speed. Admittedly it has been a few years since I last played. Is this no longer the case?

Comment: @Gnarly404 OK I realised that in LoL there are IP (earned by playing) and RP (bought for money) and that you can buy IP boosts with RP/real money, which then buy runes which do affect gameplay. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @Gnarly404: League has heroes to buy, I can not think of anything that affects gameplay MORE.

Comment: @kat0r I would argue but with that logic every single ingame item would affect gameplay. Which it does, but that doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: No, the player skins / costumes do not affect gameplay. They are cosmetic only.

Comment: `unlock these things more quickly` oh yeah, 1000x times more quickly in some games. You either spend 1000 days, or 1 day, but no, it's not P2W, we assure you. :)

Comment: There is a big difference between being able to buy runes more quickly and not being able to buy them at all.
This will make it easier, but by playing enough, you can and will have the same in game advantages than someone who paid. So it's definitely not a pay to win.

Comment: Admittedly the runes give a pretty marginal advantage over somebody without them, but it *is* an advantage. I wouldn't go so far as to call LoL "pay to win" but it does fall into the pricing model I listed in my answer.

Comment: Mentioning Counter-Strike: Global Offensive in this context is a bit odd considering that CS:GO is _not_ free to play.

Comment: Oh, yes you're right. Replaced in the answer with TF2.

Comment: Wouldn't TF2 be an example of the second case? You can buy items that affect gameplay, like weapons, but those can also be unlocked for free.